# error: The element type 'Set<Marker>' can't be assigned to the set type 'Marker'

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I am trying to place a marker for two purposes:

1. Live geolocation tracking.
2. Showing multiple markers stored in the firebase database.

so inside google map widget I tried:

```
 markers:{
    Set<Marker>.of(((marker != null) ? [marker] : [])), //This one for live geotracking
    Set<Marker>.of(markers.values), // markers stored in database
    },
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The `markers` parameter presumably expects a `Set`.  The `{}` already creates a `Set`, and you're passing a `Set<Set<Marker>>` instead of a `Set<Marker>`.  If you want to generate a `Set` from other `Set`s, you can do: `{ if (marker != null) marker, ...markers.values }`.

Comment: Thankyou very much for answering. But when i use markers.values as mentioned it shows me this error ==>  The element type 'Iterable<Marker>' can't be assigned to the set type 'Marker'.

Comment: What is your new code?

Comment: Sir i am lost here. Do i need to add any condition to show multiple marker on map.

Comment: As markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values), would do the job? I am quite new to this. please help me sir

Comment: Based on what limited information you've given, I believe that you should be able to do what I originally suggested.  If you use `...` (the spread operator) within the `Set` literal (`{}`), then you should not need to use `Set.of`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your check "marker != null"
Since marker is a set, you should check instead for "marker !={}"